# Error running SQL Server USP from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have been trying to run a SQL Server query from my C# code, but each time I get an error of

> dbo.123 Does not exist

If I log into SSMS and type in the query window `exec dbo.123` the procedure runs. Why is my code unable to see it? I am connecting to the proper server and database.

```
public DataSet RunSQLStoredProc()
{
    ebdb = new DataSet(); 
    SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    SqlQueryBuilder.Append("exec dbo.123 ");
    ebdb = DoThis(SqlQueryBuilder.ToString());
    return ebdb;
}

public DataSet DoThis(string sqlQuery)
{
    try
    {
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer1"];

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);                    
                adapter.Fill(ebdb);
                conn.Close();
            }                
        }

        return ebdb;
    }
    catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
}
```

Comment: In your `SqlQueryBuilder` set only SP name like this -.`SqlQueryBuilder.Append("123");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the statement from `SqlQueryBuilder.Append("exec dbo.123 ");`
to `SqlQueryBuilder.Append("123");`
Also there is a space after 123 which is can create a problem so remove that space too.